# javascript regex pattern for 3 alphanumeric and 3 full stops

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm new to regex and trying to write a pattern for customers to add their own custom details to a product. The idea is that a customer is allowed to have up to 3 alphanumeric characters and 3 full stops/periods, for example these would be valid entries:

```
abc
ab
a.b.c
a..bc
...
a.b.
etc
```

whereas these would be invalid:

```
abcd (too many characters)
a.... (too many .)
abcd. (too many alphanumeric)
```

I've got the following so far, but it doesn't detect when letters and . are staggered: eg. 'a.b.c'

Here's where I'm at:

```
$(document).on('keyup', 'input.custom', function() {
   currentText = $(this).val();
   reg = /^([a-zA-Z]{0,3})|([.]{0,3})$/igm;
   if (currentText.match(reg)) {
    console.log('match');
   } else {
    console.log('no match');    
   }
 });
```

It feels like I'm close, but missing something very important!

Comment: What's the issue with above regex that you feel is close and not upto the mark?

Comment: I've been using http://regexr.com/ to test it for matches, and whilst it matches for 
aab...
aab.
abc

It doesn't match for 
a.b.c.
a..bc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use lookarounds like below.

```
^(?!(?:[^.\n]*\.){4,})(?!(?:[^A-Za-z0-9\n]*[A-Za-z0-9]){4,})(?=.*[A-Za-z.0-9]).*$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/zU7dA5/21)

**Explanation:**

- `(?!(?:[^.\n]*\.){4,})` Asserts that there isn't 4 or more dots present in a string.
- `(?!(?:[^A-Za-z0-9\n]*[A-Za-z0-9]){4,})` Asserts that there isn't 4 or more alphanumeric chars present in a string.
- `(?=.*[A-Za-z.0-9])` Asserts that there must be an alphanumeric or dot present.
- Match the corresponding string only if all the above mentioned conditions are satisfied.

Answer (score 3):

It makes more sense to match with: ^[a-zA-Z0-9.]{6}$ (range could be replaced with \w if you allow underscore as well.)

And then count occurrences of periods in the text, and make sure it's 3.